# Get all the elements of class that their th vlaue are some of words

Tags: xpath

I have this html source:

```
<table class="uiInfoTable profileInfoTable uiInfoTableFixed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="label">Birthday</th>
            <td class="data">February 4, 1988</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="label">Interested In</th>
            <td class="data">women</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="label">Gender</th>
            <td class="data">male</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    //           etc....        
</table>
```

I want to get all the values of `th` and `td` that their `th` is: Birthday, Intrested In, Relationship Status and Languages..

I know that it should be something like:

```
elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@class='uiInfoTable profileInfoTable
 uiInfoTableFixed']//span[@class='label' and (text()='Birthday' or text()='Intrested 
In' or text()='Relationship Status' or text()='Languages')]")).ToList();
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found three main problems:

- Line wraps within strings to compare
- Wrong element names (`a` instead of `table`, `span` instead of whatever)
- Spelling mistake "Intrested"

Anyway, you should better select all `<tr/>` elements which have matching table header cells and then select all matching children. Also you can omit the `text()` calls which actually [could do harm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862812/695343).

This will work:

```
//table[@class='uiInfoTable profileInfoTable uiInfoTableFixed']//tr[
  th[
    @class='label' and
    (.='Birthday' or .='Interested In' or .='Relationship Status' or .='Languages')
  ]
]/*[local-name() = 'th' or local-name() = 'td']
```

This is an XPath 1.0 solution which will also work in newer XPath versions. With newer XPath versions, you could change to the much shorter

```
//table[@class='uiInfoTable profileInfoTable uiInfoTableFixed']//tr[
  th[@class='label' and
  . = ('Birthday', 'Interested In', 'Relationship Status', 'Languages')]
]/(td, th)
```